# Bootstrap X-editable a number(10,2)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, x-editable

I have a Rails/PG app with a column (data field) defined as `numeric(10,2)`

Can I in-place edit it with Bootstrap X-editable?

I tried `number` like this:

```
<a href="#" class="xeditable" data-type="number" data-pk="1" data-resource="event" data-name="hours" data-url="/events/<%= event.id %>" >
<%= event.hours %></a>
```

But, that didn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: X-editable doesn't seem to know what a `data-type="number"` means (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#inputs).

Comment: X-editable can recognize `number` - it's part of `html5types`. But, it doesn't work on my (10,2) number.

Comment: Right, I should have followed that reference. What does "doesn't work" mean? A `numeric(10,2)` should look like any other floating point number when X-editable sees it. Is something expecting an integer?

Comment: I think I'll use `text` and then `number_with_precision(event.hours, :precision => 2`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is specific to v1.5 'inline' and to Chrome 33+ and some funny html spec compliance thing on not allowing selection of numbers.

Look for a console error like this:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support
```

If you are seeing this error, then your question is probably related to this known issue: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/pull/592

If you google on that error message, you'll see some non-x-editable chatter, too.

Comment: As I write this - x-editable is stagnant.  However, I found a bug fix by digging through the outstanding pull requests (sorry - I don't have the link and its probably OBE by the time you read this.)